# Numpy.i typemap for multiple arrays of different types

Tags: python, arrays, c, swig, typemaps

I have a C function which takes, among other arguments, 3 arrays of differents types :
`void create_signal(double ztab[], ..., int *pdata, ..., char ranging[], ...);` and I want to use this function in a Python module using SWIG.

I have already figured out how to use C functions which take in an array with *numpy.i* typemaps :
`%apply (double* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double xtab[], int length)}` for instance,

or even 2 arrays of same type :
`apply (double* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double xtab[], int length_x), (double ytab[], int length_y)}`

but I can't figure out if it is possible to do so if the arrays are of different types (in my case, `int`, `double`, and `char`), or if I should rewrite my own typemap.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It works out of the box. Simply apply multiple of the NumPy typemaps. You can apply them one by one, there is no need to write multiple matches on the right-hand side. E.g. `%apply (double* IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(const double* pData,  const int nx, const int ny)};` will apply on all functions where it matches a fraction of the arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, here goes an example

test.h

```
#pragma once

void multipleInputs(const float* data, const int nData,
                    const float* pos, const int nPositions, const int nDim);
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

#include <cstdio>

void multipleInputs(const float* data, const int nData,
                    const float* pos, const int nPositions, const int nDim)
{
  if (nData > 0) {
    printf("%d'th element is: %f\n", (nData-1), data[nData-1]);
  }
  if ((nDim > 0) && (nPositions > 0)){
    printf("%d'th dimension of the %d'th element is: %f\n",
           (nDim-1), (nPositions-1), data[nData-1]);
  }
}
```

test.i

```
%module example
%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  #include "test.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init {
  import_array();
}

%apply (float* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) \
{(const float* data, const int nData)}

%apply (float* IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) \
{(const float* pos, const int nPositions, const int nDim)};

%include "test.h"
```

setup.py

```
import numpy

from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(name="example",
      py_modules=["example"],
      ext_modules=[Extension("_example",
                             ["test.i","test.cpp"],
                             include_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), '.'],
                             swig_opts=['-c++', '-I.'],
      )]
)
```

test.py

```
import example
example.multipleInputs(np.ones((10),dtype=np.float32), 
                       np.ones((10,10),dtype=np.float32))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it worked out of the box as you said. Thank you for the example, it has proven most useful !

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as accepted